# How to alter random post code to prevent duplicates

Tags: php, woocommerce

I used a code I found on this website (stackoverflow) and it worked, it was to make posts random. It works, but it duplicates posts, here is the code

```php
 // Set default orderby query to "rand" for shop archive pages
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'shop_default_orderby_rand' );
function shop_default_orderby_rand( $query ) {
    if ( is_shop() && ( ! isset($_GET['orderby']) || 'menu_order' === $_GET['orderby'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
}
```

It shows some products as duplicates in the archive as people scroll. How can I alter the code to prevent this?

Comment: "as people scroll" Is this an infinite scroll page, where as you scroll an AJAX call is made to fetch more items?

Comment: Hello! Yes it is

Comment: The short answer is no, or at least not without a lot of work. The `orderby` is passed directly to the database, and the database doesn't have a concept of "previous query" or which request belongs to which user, both of which are needed. If you really wanted to build such a thing, my recommendation would be to query the database for **all** post IDs on page load and randomize those. Then your first load would show 10 of those, and the AJAX logic would pull from this pool. So the AJAX isn't asking for random anymore, that was decided ahead of time. Unfortunately I don't have time to write more

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I really appreciate this answer